# Environment mapping controls missing in Texture context tab - Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing

It seems Environment mapping controls are missing in the Texture context tab in Blender 2.8. Any reason for this?

Thanks
JK

Comment: Environment mapping is done in the *World* tab.

Comment: Yes, I have the map assigned in World tab. I'm talking about this:

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UMIxt0q

Answer (score 0):

The environment map can be set in the *World* tab or alternatively by using nodes in the *Shader Editor*.

To setup the environment map as depicted below, perform the following steps in the *World* tab on the default world configuration which only consists of a *Background* node connected to the *World Output*.

1. Click on the circular button for *Color* and select *Environment Texture* from the dropdown
2. Click on *Vector* and select *Mapping*
3. Click on the circular button behind *Vector* in *Mapping* and select *Generated*

[image: World tab]

[image: Shader editor]